# Flutter web-hosted app doesn't recognize external functions

Tags: flutter, github-pages, flutter-web, solana, dart-js-interop

I'm hosting a web made on Flutter on GitHub pages and I'm using [Dart-JS interop](https://pub.dev/packages/js) for connecting a Solana wallet. When I test locally I can connect to it and works fine but once I host the web on GitHub Pages I get the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: p.isPhantomInstalled is not a function**

This is my Dart code:

```
    @JS('walletModule.ClientWallet')
    class ClientWallet {
      external Future<void> connect();
      external void disconnect();
      external String get address;
      external Future<void> signTransaction();
      external bool isPhantomInstalled();
    }
    
    class WalletController extends GetxController {
    
      Future<void> connectWallet(context) async {
        ClientWallet wallet = ClientWallet();
        if (wallet.isPhantomInstalled()) {
          await promiseToFuture(wallet.connect());
          createSnackbar('success', 'Wallet Connected');
        } else {
          createSnackbar('error', 'No Phantom wallet detected');
        }
      }
```

This is my JS code:

```
class ClientWallet {

    constructor() {
        this.address = '';
    }

    async connect() {
        const resp = await window.solana.connect();
        this.address = resp.publicKey.toString();
    }

    address() {
        return this.address;
    }

    isPhantomInstalled() {
        return window.solana && window.solana.isPhantom;
    }

    disconnect() {
        window.solana.disconnect();
    }
}

var walletModule = { ClientWallet: ClientWallet };
```

It seems that when hosted, the app doesn't recognize the **external** functions? I have no clue why or how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your original post on connecting a Phantom wallet with Flutter, I decided to try it out myself, and I eventually ran into the same issue as you, down the to exact function call!

The solution (workaround) for me was to *use standalone functions instead of methods*.

I do not know why, but for some reason the Dart-JS interop stopped working on class instances after `flutter build web`. My minified JS code with class instances played nice with `flutter run -d chrome`.

Edit:

This is the `phantom.ts` I got working.

```
const solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');

export async function connect(): solanaWeb3.PublicKey {
  const resp = await window.solana.connect();
  return new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(resp.publicKey.toString());
}

export function disconnect() {
  window.solana.disconnect();
}

export function isPhantomInstalled(): bool {
  return window.solana && window.solana.isPhantom;
}

export async function signTransaction(tx: solanaWeb3.Transaction): solanaWeb3.Transaction {
  return await window.solana.signTransaction(tx);
}
```

Then Dart-side, the interop is the same, just no class definition. I'm going to write a Medium post / release a GitHub repo with an example soon.

Edit 2:
[Medium post / repo can be found here](https://blog.auguron.com/flutter-dapps-on-solana-364e81fe73ca)

Comment: Glad to know that code was useful to someone! Can you share a code snippet on how you made it work? I was able to use standalone functions instead of methods and it works locally but it still doesn't work when served.

Comment: I edited my original example to show what I got working. It sounds like your problem is more related to paths and namespaces than anything else. How are you injecting the JS into your Flutter build / HTML?

Comment: Thanks @HelmetFace, worked like a charm. Please, do not hesitate to link here the Medium article, I'll be waiting to read it!

Comment: I'm also very interested in this. I've been struggling to work out how to get the metadata json for an NFT in Flutter. I think your article may help me!

Comment: Here's the article and accompanying GitHub repo for those interested.
https://blog.auguron.com/flutter-dapps-on-solana-364e81fe73ca